# Removing a folder from the URL using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do you remove a folder from the URL?
I have a Drupal installation in a folder and I would like to remove that subfolder from the URL.

So instead of:

```
www.example.com/subfolder/*
```

I would like the url to be:

```
www.example.com/*
```

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And to redirect direct requests of `/subfolder/…`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or, even better, change your [document root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) to that subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: oh, @Gumbo solutions are better!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the .* like this:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/subfolder/ [L]

Comment: "subfolder" should come before "$1".

Comment: (.*) eats all avaiable characters, so no need to ^, i think